# General Carathéodory Theorem why greater than to equal

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $X$ be a nonempty set and $\mu^*:P(X)\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be an outer measure on $X.$ Consider a class of  the subsets of $X$ by

$$m_{\mu}=\{A \in P(X):\mu^*(E)\ge \mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E/A)\;\;\forall E\in P(X)\}.$$

Then $m_{_\mu}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on subsets of X and the restriction of $\mu^*$ to $m_{\mu},$ that is $\mu:m_{_\mu}\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ given by $\mu(A):=\mu^*(A)$ is a measure on $X$.

In addition, the measure space $(X,m_{\mu},\mu^*)$ is complete, that is, if $\mu^*(A)=0$,then $A\in m_{\mu}.$

My doubt is why my course instructor has chosen the set
$m_{\mu}
=\{A$ $ \in$ $ P(X):\mu^*(E)\ge \mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E/A)$ ,$\forall E\in P(X) \}$
with greater and equal to rather than equal.

I think by subadditivity it will be just
$\mu^*(E)= \mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E/A),\;\forall E\in P(X).$

2)$\mu^*(E)\ge \mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E/A),\;\;\forall E\in P(X)$

similarly  has define $L(R^k)=\{A$ $ \subset$ $ R^k:\mu^*(E)\ge \mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E/A)$ ,$\forall E\subset R^k  \}$
[image]
he says outer measure means measuring from out side.

He has given this example and told about $L(R)$ with strict inequality and says this is why strict inequality is there

Comment: The first sentence makes no sense (honest, I don't know what you're trying to say): "Let $\dots "\mu^*\dots$ be an outer measure on $X$ by". Huh? There's a word missing or something

Comment: No this is what he stated please elaborate what you exactly trying to say?

Comment: Huh? I didn't say it wasn't "what he stated", I said it makes no sense. What I'm trying to say is the first sentence makes no sense. Sorry, I thought that was clear...

Comment: Please tell after edit.

Comment: The first sentence is just fine, except for a small detail of grammar. There's a very important word missing from the second sentence

Comment: Now Please tell is class of subsets necessary here ?are we defining some equivalence classes here .I have studied about them in algebra.

Comment: ??? We're trying to define a measure. First we need to define a $\sigma$-algebra to be the domain of that measure. A $\sigma$-algebra _is_ a class of subsets...

Comment: Yes this set is a sigma algebra and hence forms domain of measures .But what about sub additivity which rules out possibility of greater than equal to just strict equality in set $m_{\mu}$.Why he has chosen set of this type?

Comment: Yes, subaddititvity shows that the $\ge$ in the definition of $m_\mu$ is equivalent to $=$. _Hence_ the definition is often stated with $\ge$, because showing $a\ge b$ is easier than showing $a=b$.

Comment: But how is it easier in equality this case. I am not able to see that can you give some example .Please

Comment: ,and what will happen to set for which it is '>'.

Comment: Showing $a\ge b$ is easier than showing $a=b$. Proof: if you show $a=b$ that proof _contains_ a proof that $a\ge b$. (What will happen for sets where it's $>$? First, that's irrelevant to the definition; such a set is simply not in $m_\mu$. But in fact subadditvity shows there is no such set.)

Comment: Now please tell what will happen in above diagram ?all the three triangles are measurable and the bigger triangle i.e. outer sum have more measure(i.e. by0.5)

Comment: That "diagram" is wrong, or misleading. It does _not_ show three triangles, because the two small triangles are not similar! $5/11\ne 9/20$.

Comment: I told him I calculated area he says that its Numerical thing just difference in decimal don't make much difference . He says let's say you have a=0.1 then a^2=0.01.And more over 9/20=0.45 and 5/11=0.454545...

Comment: I missed the point to that non-example. Oh: "He has given this example and told about L(R) with strict inequality and says this is why strict inequality is there". This is simply wrong. mumbling "numerical thing" does not change the fact that outer measure is subadditive.